# Receiving incorrect results from the PHP function strtotime()

Tags: php

I start with two dates:

```
$endDate   = '2013-11-30 18:30:00';
$beginDate = '2013-10-31 18:30:00';
```

Then, I took date difference using following code:

```
$diff = abs(strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($beginDate));
```

Next, I check the date difference by

```
$days = $diff / (60*60*24);
```

However, it returns a fractional day, such as `30.041666666667`.  I don't want to get this fractional.  Why this happening?  This problem occurs in some cases only.

Comment: That's working exactly how you wrote it.  You can either format the output or use [`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) to get just the `30`.

Comment: You can also use this SO post about [calculating relative time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time) (such as "2 days ago").  It is for `C#` but the logic is very easy to put in `PHP` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2013-11-21 12:59:00");
    $date2 = new DateTime("2013-11-21 13:01:00");
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2); 

    echo "DIFF: ".$interval->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s");
```

Visit the link for [details](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)

Comment: but what is diff function in $interval = $date1->diff($date2); 
?

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `mktime()` function for calculate diff.

```
<?php
$endDate   = '2013-11-30 18:30:00';
$endDateTemp = explode(' ', $endDate);
$endDateArr1 = explode('-', $endDateTemp[0]);
$endDateArr2 = explode(':', $endDateTemp[1]);
$endTimestamp = mktime($endDateArr2[0], $endDateArr2[1], $endDateArr2[2], $endDateArr1[1], $endDateArr1[2], $endDateArr1[0]);
$beginDate = '2013-10-31 18:30:00';
$beginDateTemp = explode(' ', $beginDate);
$beginDateArr1 = explode('-', $beginDateTemp[0]);
$beginDateArr2 = explode(':', $beginDateTemp[1]);
$beginTimestamp = mktime($beginDateArr2[0], $beginDateArr2[1], $beginDateArr2[2], $beginDateArr1[1], $beginDateArr1[2], $beginDateArr1[0]);
$diff = $endTimestamp - $beginTimestamp;
$day = $diff/(24*60*60);
?>
```

Comment: you should add an example to your answer to make it more complete or link to the function documentation at least

Comment: your edit to the question was rejected because it changed the actual question being asked.  don't make modifications that turn someone else's post into something entirely different.

Comment: how to use this mktime() ? can you give me an example from my question?

Comment: but this also output a fractional date difference. I got an output of 30.041666666667. I need to get 30 days only.